# Tkinter Compilate form

Tags: tkinter

Hi all I would like to run a python script with Tkinter, basically the user has to enter the username and password and select the year and month, the problem I don't know how to combine it all together, I would like when I press the login button, the data is entered into the script that is to be run.

```
ws = Tk()
ws.title("Monatseinteilungs Tool")
ws.geometry("500x300")
label = Label(ws)

mytext=StringVar()
year=IntVar()
print(year)
monats=StringVar()
jahr = StringVar()
Label(ws, text="Benuzername:").grid(row=0, sticky=W)
Label(ws, text="Password:").grid(row=1, sticky=W)
Label(ws, text="Result:").grid(row=3, sticky=W)

result=Label(ws, text="", textvariable=mytext).grid(row=3,column=1, sticky=W)
 
entry1 = Entry(ws)
entry2 = Entry(ws)
 
entry1.grid(row=0, column=1)
entry2.grid(row=1, column=1)
var = IntVar()
#Jahr Wählen#
Label(ws, text="Wähle das Jahr:").grid(row=4, sticky=W)
R1 = Radiobutton(ws, text = "2022", variable = year, value = 2022, command=login)
R1.grid(column=0, row=5)
R2 = Radiobutton(ws, text = "2021", variable = year, value = 2021, command=login)
R2.grid(column=0, row=6)
#Jahr Wählen#

#Monat Wählen#
Label(ws, text="Wähle das Jahr:").grid(row=4, sticky=W)
M1 = Radiobutton(ws, text = "Januar", variable = monats, value = '01', command=mese)
M1.grid(column=1, row=5)
M2 = Radiobutton(ws, text = "Februar", variable = monats, value = '02', command=mese)
M2.grid(column=1, row=6)
M3 = Radiobutton(ws, text = "März", variable = monats, value = '03', command=mese)
M3.grid(column=1, row=7)
M4 = Radiobutton(ws, text = "April", variable = monats, value = '04', command=mese)
M4.grid(column=2, row=5)
M5 = Radiobutton(ws, text = "Mai", variable = monats, value = '05', command=mese)
M5.grid(column=2, row=6)
M6 = Radiobutton(ws, text = "Juni", variable = monats, value = '06', command=mese)
M6.grid(column=2, row=7)
M7 = Radiobutton(ws, text = "Juli", variable = monats, value = '07', command=mese)
M7.grid(column=3, row=5)
M8 = Radiobutton(ws, text = "August", variable = monats, value = '08', command=mese)
M8.grid(column=3, row=6)
M9 = Radiobutton(ws, text = "September", variable = monats, value = '09', command=mese)
M9.grid(column=3, row=7)
M10 = Radiobutton(ws, text = "Oktober", variable = monats, value = '10', command=mese)
M10.grid(column=4, row=5)
M11 = Radiobutton(ws, text = "November", variable = monats, value = '11', command=mese)
M11.grid(column=4, row=6)
M12 = Radiobutton(ws, text = "Dezember", variable = monats, value = '12', command=mese)
M12.grid(column=4, row=7)

button = Button(ws, text="Login", command=login)
button.grid(row=0, column=2,columnspan=2, rowspan=2,sticky=W+E+N+S, padx=5, pady=5)


ws.mainloop()
```

Comment: Where is the `login()`?

Comment: The login works, only I can't put together the login data and the radial buttons, if I select the month or year first the login starts directly because it has the same login command as the login button, if I give it another name I don't know how to integrate the values in the login def...

Comment: Then why don't you remove the `command` option from `R1` and `R2`?

Comment: and how do I return the value of the radial buttons to the login def?

Comment: You can use `year.get()` and `monats.get()` inside `login()` to get the selected year and month number.

Comment: Oh thank you very much, I've been going crazy for two days! :-)